# In how many instructions are global and static variables are fetched?

Tags: c

In how many instructions are global and static variables are fetched? 
As we know local or automatic variables are fetched in 1 microprocessor instruction, in how many instructions are global and static variables are fetched? Does it costs same as fetching dynamic variables from heap? or a bit less.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the C specification doesn't specify how many instructions are required for a variable fetch, and that the number of instructions that it actually requires is compiler and implementation-dependent.

Comment: The answer will depend on the compiler and processor that you're using. The best way to find out for a particular combination of compiler and processor would be compile an example program, disassemble it and look at the instructions that the compiler is producing.

Comment: Time to start looking at assembly and reading your processor documentation.

Comment: I was just curios to know about it. I think like everyone even OS wants some space, known as abstraction :)

Comment: You can even try to write two programs which respectively stores static and global variables, and then testing their time using time utility available in Unix.

Answer (score 10):

The answer may be one of:

(a) Thousands, because the global variable is in memory that is not currently mapped, so accessing it causes an exception which causes the operating system to load the page.

(b) Many, because the global variable is in a dynamic library which has to be loaded and linked before the variable can be accessed.

(c) Several, because the address of the variable has to be assembled from parts and/or relocation information.

(d) One, because the address is computed from immediate data in the instruction and/or data already in registers, such as a global data pointer.

(e) Zero, because optimization has kept the variable in a register from previous operations.

Answer (score 1):

> In how many instructions are global and static variables are fetched?

Anywhere from zero (already cached in a register) to many depending on many factors.

> As we know local or automatic variables are fetched in 1
>   microprocessor instruction [...]

We can't know this, since it is not true for most objects larger than some implementation-specific limit. And then there are C *Interpreters* where that limit may well be 0 and *all* loads require dozens if not hundreds of instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the computer architecture and context. The C specification doesn't specify this, and it will depend upon what compiler and what optimization options you are using.